# Android Background service crash while the internet is off

Tags: android, gps

```
public class MyService extends BackgroundService implements LocationListener {

    private final static String TAG = MyService.class.getSimpleName();
    private String mHelloTo = "World";
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    boolean ineternetAvailable = false;
    private String provider;
    Context context;
    int bat_level = 0;
    GPSTracker gps;
    String username;
    CommentsDataSource datasource;
    NetworkConnectivityListener nw;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        context = getApplicationContext();
        datasource = new CommentsDataSource(context);
        gps = new GPSTracker(context);
        datasource.open();
        mHelloTo = datasource.getComment_1();

        nw = new NetworkConnectivityListener();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doWork() {
        // ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(context);

        **JSONObject result = new JSONObject();

        try {

            nw.startListening(context);
            context.registerReceiver(this.batteryInfoReceiver,
                    new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
            int level = 0;

            String msg = "KAsun " + mHelloTo + " - its currently "
                    + gps.getLongitude();
            result.put("Message", msg);
            Log.i("Networ", nw.getState().toString());

            if (nw.getState().toString().equals("CONNECTED")) {
                sendPostRequest("" + gps.getLongitude(),
                        "" + gps.getLatitude(), this.mHelloTo, "" + bat_level);
            }

            else {
                Handler h = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
                h.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                                "Internet Connection is Not Available",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

            }
            Log.d(TAG, msg);
            datasource.close();**

        } catch (JSONException e) {
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject getConfig() {
        JSONObject result = new JSONObject();

        try {
            result.put("HelloTo", this.mHelloTo);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void setConfig(JSONObject config) {
        try {
            if (config.has("HelloTo"))
                this.mHelloTo = config.getString("HelloTo");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        }

    }



    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private BroadcastReceiver batteryInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            bat_level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);

        }
    };

    private void sendPostRequest(String lo, String la, String username,
            String batlevel) {

        class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                String lo = params[0];
                String la = params[1];
                String username = params[2];
                String b_level = params[3];

                System.out.println("*** doInBackground ** paramUsername " + lo
                        + " paramPassword :" + la + "Username" + username
                        + "BatLevel" + b_level);

                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                // In a POST request, we don't pass the values in the URL.
                // Therefore we use only the web page URL as the parameter of
                // the HttpPost argument
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                        "http://gateway.ceylonlinux.com/Ceylon_Steel/service/markGPSLocation");

                BasicNameValuePair longtiude = new BasicNameValuePair(
                        "latitude", lo);
                BasicNameValuePair lattiude = new BasicNameValuePair(
                        "longitude", la);
                BasicNameValuePair username_param = new BasicNameValuePair(
                        "userName", username);
                BasicNameValuePair batery_level = new BasicNameValuePair(
                        "batteryLevel", b_level);

                // We add the content that we want to pass with the POST request
                // to as name-value pairs
                // Now we put those sending details to an ArrayList with type
                // safe of NameValuePair
                List<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList();
                nameValuePairList.add(longtiude);
                nameValuePairList.add(lattiude);
                nameValuePairList.add(username_param);
                nameValuePairList.add(batery_level);

                try {
                    // UrlEncodedFormEntity is an entity composed of a list of
                    // url-encoded pairs.
                    // This is typically useful while sending an HTTP POST
                    // request.
                    UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFormEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                            nameValuePairList);

                    // setEntity() hands the entity (here it is
                    // urlEncodedFormEntity) to the request.
                    httpPost.setEntity(urlEncodedFormEntity);

                    try {
                        // HttpResponse is an interface just like HttpPost.
                        // Therefore we can't initialize them
                        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient
                                .execute(httpPost);

                        // According to the JAVA API, InputStream constructor do
                        // nothing.
                        // So we can't initialize InputStream although it is not
                        // an interface
                        InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity()
                                .getContent();

                        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                                inputStream);

                        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                                inputStreamReader);

                        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                        String bufferedStrChunk = null;

                        while ((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
                        }

                        return stringBuilder.toString();

                    } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
                        System.out
                                .println("First Exception caz of HttpResponese :"
                                        + cpe);
                        cpe.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        System.out
                                .println("Second Exception caz of HttpResponse :"
                                        + ioe);
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                    System.out
                            .println("An Exception given because of U     rlEncodedFormEntity argument :"
                                    + uee);
                    uee.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                Log.i("Result", result);

            }
        }

        SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
        sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(lo, la, username, batlevel);

    }

}
```

Above Code works as Background service to get the current gps cordinetes and Send it to the Server within each 10 second.Before the data is sent to the server program it self check weather the internet connection is available or not through a broadcast service.It works fine(if internet connection available it send **CONNECTED** if not send **DISCONNECTED**).But if i switched off the internet connection while data is sending the app will crash.

```
 02-15 10:41:40.460: W/System.err(10109): java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
02-15 10:41:40.468: W/System.err(10109):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:552)
02-15 10:41:40.476: W/System.err(10109):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:516)
02-15 10:41:40.500: W/System.err(10109):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
02-15 10:41:40.507: W/System.err(10109):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
02-15 10:41:40.515: W/System.err(10109):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
                        System.out
                                .println("First Exception caz of HttpResponese :"
                                        + cpe);
                        cpe.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    catch (SocketTimeoutException s) {

                    } catch (HttpHostConnectException e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    } catch (SocketException e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }
```

I should add the above exceptions to handle the errors